# Getting error in Google App Script to fetch data from JSON api Webservice and write them to google spreadsheet

Tags: json, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-api-javascript-client

I am trying to get data using Google App Script from a web service via api which is in json format and write it to my google sheet spreadsheet but getting error that says "The number of rows in the range must be at least 1. (line 22)"

I got a script from google search which I wrote it in the script editor of google sheets and given all permissions. Can someone please tell me how to get past the error?

Thanks

```
// Taken from here --> https://gist.github.com/varun-raj/5350595a730a62ca1954

function pullJSON() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

  var url="https://cricapi.com/api/fantasySummary?apikey=apikey"; // Paste your JSON URL here

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url); // get feed
  var dataAll = JSON.parse(response.getContentText()); //
  var dataSet = dataAll;

  var rows = [],
      data;

  for (i = 0; i < dataSet.length; i++) {
    data = dataSet[i];
    rows.push([data.data, data.team, data.players, data.name]); //your JSON entities here
  }

  dataRange = sheet.getRange(1, 1, rows.length, 4); // 4 Denotes total number of entites
  dataRange.setValues(rows);

}
```

Given below value of response

```
{"dateTimeGMT":"2019-05-14T12:00:00.000Z","data":{"fielding":[{"title":"Fielding for Pakistan Innings","scores":[{"name":"CR Woakes","runout":0,"stumped":0,"bowled":2,"lbw":0,"catch":1,"pid":"247235"},{"name":"Chris Jordan","runout":0,"stumped":0,"bowled":0,"lbw":0,"catch":1,"pid":288992},{"name":"JJ Roy","runout":0,"stumped":0,"bowled":0,"lbw":0,"catch":1,"pid":"298438"},{"name":"JE Root","runout":0,"stumped":0,"bowled":0,"lbw":0,"catch":1,"pid":"303669"},{"name":"DJ Willey","runout":0,"stumped":0,"bowled":1,"lbw":0,"catch":1,"pid":"308251"},{"name":"TK Curran","runout":1,"stumped":0,"bowled":1,"lbw":1,"catch":0,"pid":"550235"}]},{"title":"Fielding for England Innings","scores":[{"name":"Asif Ali","runout":0,"stumped":0,"bowled":0,"lbw":0,"catch":1,"pid":"494230"},{"name":"Junaid Khan","runout":0,"stumped":0,"bowled":1,"lbw":0,"catch":0,"pid":"259551"},{"name":"Babar Azam","runout":0,"stumped":0,"bowled":0,"lbw":0,"catch":1,"pid":"348144"},{"name":"Shaheen Shah Afridi","runout":1,"stumped":0,"bowled":0,"lbw":0,"catch":0,"pid":"1072470"}]}],"bowling":[{"scores":[{"6s":1,"4s":9,"0s":28,"Econ":"6.70","W":"4","R":"67","M":"0","O":"10","bowler":"CR Woakes","pid":"247235"},{"6s":3,"4s":10,"0s":26,"Econ":"8.60","W":"1","R":"86","M":"0","O":"10","bowler":"DJ Willey","pid":"308251"},{"6s":1,"4s":1,"0s":14,"Econ":"5.33","W":"0","R":"32","M":"0","O":"6","bowler":"MM Ali","pid":"8917"},{"6s":0,"4s":5,"0s":20,"Econ":"6.11","W":"1","R":"55","M":"0","O":"9","bowler":"LE Plunkett","pid":"19264"},{"6s":2,"4s":7,"0s":21,"Econ":"7.40","W":"2","R":"74","M":"0","O":"10","bowler":"TK Curran","pid":"550235"},{"6s":0,"4s":3,"0s":3,"Econ":"8.50","W":"0","R":"34","M":"0","O":"4","bowler":"BA Stokes","pid":"311158"},{"6s":0,"4s":1,"0s":1,"Econ":"9.00","W":"0","R":"9","M":"0","O":"1","bowler":"JL Denly","pid":"12454"}],"title":"Bowling To Pakistan Innings"},{"scores":[{"6s":3,"4s":5,"0s":24,"Econ":"7.12","W":"1","R":"57","M":"0","O":"8","bowler":"Junaid Khan","pid":"259551"},{"6s":3,"4s":11,"0s":25,"Econ":"8.30","W":"0","R":"83","M":"0","O":"10","bowler":"Shaheen Shah Afridi","pid":"1072470"},{"6s":0,"4s":8,"0s":20,"Econ":"6.87","W":"0","R":"55","M":"0","O":"8","bowler":"Hasan Ali","pid":"681305"},{"6s":4,"4s":2,"0s":15,"Econ":"8.28","W":"1","R":"58","M":"0","O":"7","bowler":"Imad Wasim","pid":"227758"},{"6s":4,"4s":7,"0s":28,"Econ":"8.33","W":"1","R":"75","M":"0","O":"9","bowler":"Faheem Ashraf","pid":"681117"},{"6s":2,"4s":0,"0s":3,"Econ":"9.50","W":"0","R":"19","M":"0","O":"2","bowler":"Haris Sohail","pid":"318788"},{"6s":0,"4s":1,"0s":0,"Econ":"10.80","W":"0","R":"9","M":"0","O":"0.5","bowler":"Asif Ali","pid":"494230"}],"title":"Bowling To England Innings"}],"batting":[{"scores":[{"dismissal-by":{"name":"TK Curran","pid":"550235"},"dismissal":"bowled","SR":115,"6s":1,"4s":16,"B":131,"R":151,"dismissal-info":" b Curran","batsman":"Imam-ul-Haq","pid":"568276"},{"dismissal-by":{"name":"JE Root","pid":"303669"},"dismissal":"catch","SR":50,"6s":0,"4s":0,"B":4,"R":2,"dismissal-info":"c Root b Woakes","batsman":"Fakhar Zaman","pid":"512191"},{"dismissal-by":{"name":"CR Woakes","pid":"247235"},"dismissal":"bowled","SR":136,"6s":0,"4s":3,"B":11,"R":15,"dismissal-info":" b Woakes","batsman":"Babar Azam","pid":"348144"},{"dismissal-by":[{"name":"TK Curran","pid":"550235"}],"dismissal":"runout","SR":100,"6s":0,"4s":7,"B":41,"R":41,"dismissal-info":"run out (Curran)","batsman":"Haris Sohail","pid":"318788"},{"dismissal-by":{"name":"Chris Jordan","pid":288992},"dismissal":"catch","SR":79,"6s":0,"4s":2,"B":34,"R":27,"dismissal-info":"c sub (CJ Jordan) b Plunkett","batsman":"Sarfaraz Ahmed (c)  ","pid":"227760"},{"dismissal-by":{"name":"JJ Roy","pid":"298438"},"dismissal":"catch","SR":120,"6s":3,"4s":2,"B":43,"R":52,"dismissal-info":"c Roy b Woakes","batsman":"Asif Ali","pid":"494230"},{"dismissal-by":{"name":"CR Woakes","pid":"247235"},"dismissal":"catch & bowled","SR":183,"6s":0,"4s":4,"B":12,"R":22,"dismissal-info":"c & b Woakes","batsman":"Imad Wasim","pid":"227758"},{"dismissal-by":{"name":"TK Curran","pid":"550235"},"dismissal":"lbw","SR":118,"6s":0,"4s":1,"B":11,"R":13,"dismissal-info":"lbw b Curran","batsman":"Faheem Ashraf","pid":"681117"},{"dismissal":"not out","SR":200,"6s":2,"4s":1,"B":9,"R":18,"dismissal-info":"not out","batsman":"Hasan Ali","pid":"681305"},{"dismissal-by":{"name":"DJ Willey","pid":"308251"},"dismissal":"catch & bowled","SR":175,"6s":1,"4s":0,"B":4,"R":7,"dismissal-info":"c & b Willey","batsman":"Shaheen Shah Afridi","pid":"1072470"},{"dismissal":"not out","SR":0,"6s":0,"4s":0,"B":0,"R":0,"dismissal-info":"not out","batsman":"Junaid Khan","pid":"259551"},{"SR":"","6s":"","4s":"","B":"","R":"","dismissal-info":"","detail":"10 (lb 1, w 9)","batsman":"Extras","pid":0}],"title":"Pakistan Innings"},{"scores":[{"dismissal-by":{"name":"Asif Ali","pid":"494230"},"dismissal":"catch","SR":138,"6s":4,"4s":8,"B":55,"R":76,"dismissal-info":"c Asif Ali b Faheem Ashraf","batsman":"JJ Roy","pid":"298438"},{"dismissal-by":{"name":"Junaid Khan","pid":"259551"},"dismissal":"bowled","SR":137,"6s":5,"4s":15,"B":93,"R":128,"dismissal-info":" b Junaid Khan","batsman":"JM Bairstow  ","pid":"297433"},{"dismissal-by":{"name":"Babar Azam","pid":"348144"},"dismissal":"catch","SR":119,"6s":1,"4s":4,"B":36,"R":43,"dismissal-info":"c Babar Azam b Imad Wasim","batsman":"JE Root","pid":"303669"},{"dismissal-by":[{"name":"Shaheen Shah Afridi","pid":"1072470"}],"dismissal":"runout","SR":97,"6s":2,"4s":2,"B":38,"R":37,"dismissal-info":"run out (Shaheen Shah Afridi)","batsman":"BA Stokes","pid":"311158"},{"dismissal":"not out","SR":127,"6s":3,"4s":4,"B":36,"R":46,"dismissal-info":"not out","batsman":"MM Ali","pid":"8917"},{"dismissal":"not out","SR":141,"6s":1,"4s":1,"B":12,"R":17,"dismissal-info":"not out","batsman":"EJG Morgan (c)","pid":"24598"},{"SR":"","6s":"","4s":"","B":"","R":"","dismissal-info":"","detail":"12 (lb 3, nb 1, w 8)","batsman":"Extras","pid":0}],"title":"England Innings"}],"team":[{"players":[{"name":"JJ Roy","pid":"298438"},{"name":"JM Bairstow","pid":"297433"},{"name":"JE Root","pid":"303669"},{"name":"BA Stokes","pid":"311158"},{"name":"MM Ali","pid":"8917"},{"name":"EJG Morgan","pid":"24598"},{"name":"JL Denly","pid":"12454"},{"name":"TK Curran","pid":"550235"},{"name":"CR Woakes","pid":"247235"},{"name":"DJ Willey","pid":"308251"},{"name":"LE Plunkett","pid":"19264"}],"name":"England"},{"players":[{"name":"Imam-ul-Haq","pid":"568276"},{"name":"Fakhar Zaman","pid":"512191"},{"name":"Babar Azam","pid":"348144"},{"name":"Haris Sohail","pid":"318788"},{"name":"Sarfaraz Ahmed","pid":"227760"},{"name":"Asif Ali","pid":"494230"},{"name":"Imad Wasim","pid":"227758"},{"name":"Faheem Ashraf","pid":"681117"},{"name":"Hasan Ali","pid":"681305"},{"name":"Shaheen Shah Afridi","pid":"1072470"},{"name":"Junaid Khan","pid":"259551"}],"name":"Pakistan"}],"man-of-the-match":{"name":"JM Bairstow","pid":"297433"},"toss_winner_team":"England","winner_team":"England","matchStarted":true},"type":"ODI","cache3":true,"creditsLeft":202,"v":"1","ttl":6,"provider":{"source":"Various","url":"https://cricapi.com/","pubDate":"2019-05-23T07:15:07.670Z"}}
```

The output what I am looking is this:

**If I supply data->team->players->name, it should output this (only name)**
[image]

**If I supply data->team->Players, it should output this(name+pid)**
[image]

**Similarly if I supply any other group, it should output the respective values.**

Comment: Can you provide the value of ``response``?

Comment: Updated value of response in the question. Thanks for looking into it. Also updated apikey in the question.

Comment: Thank you for adding the information. If the added value is ``response.getContentText()``, ``dataSet.length`` becomes ``undefined``. By this, ``rows`` becomes ``[]``. I think that the reason of your error is this. Although I thought that I tried to modify your script, unfortunately from your question I couldn't understand about the output you want. So I posted this as a comment. I apologize for my poor English skill.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I dont know if you work with google apps script & google sheets. I need the output in google spreadsheets in the active worksheet in tabular format where all the values goes under the respective headings. 'rows.push([data.data, data.team, data.players, data.name])' should bring a list of players one below the other along with which team they belong to. I hope I am explaining my question properly.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. If ``data`` of your reply is ``dataSet[i]``, the for loop doesn't work. So I cannot understand about ``rows.push([data.data, data.team, data.players, data.name])``. Can you provide the output sample you want? Even if you cannot do it, don't worry. The reason I couldn't understand about your output is due to my poor English skill. Other users will be able to understand about it.

Comment: Thanks again. I have updated desired output in the question. Hope I will get some solution on how to get the desired output.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I couldn't understand about your additional images. I don't want to trouble you any further. So when I could understand about your goal, I would like to think of about your solution. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill.

Comment: I truly appreciate your time to help me with my issue. Thank you so much. God bless ! Looking forward for getting a solution on my problem.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I think that the values of your 2 images can be retrieved by a script. But I cannot understand about ``Similarly if I supply any other group, it should output the respective values.``, yet. I apologize for this situation. So can I ask you about this?

Comment: I appreciate if you can help me how to retrieve the values by a script. By other group I mean, other data that is available in the json output. Eg. data->fielding or data->batting or data->bowling. I hope I have explained what you are asking for. Even if you help me retrieve values of the images I uploaded, I will try to get other values myself by understanding your script. Thanks

Comment: Thank you for replying. 1. About ``data->fielding or data->batting or data->bowling``, it seems that those are objects. Can I ask you about the output you want? 2. If you want to retrieve various values by inputting various parameters, the structures of ``fielding``, ``batting`` and ``bowling`` are the same. But the structure of ``team`` is different from others. About this, how do you want to do? 3. Are there other keys you want except for ``fielding``, ``batting``, ``bowling`` and ``team``?

Comment: 1. the output what I need is similar to the images I posted. Data in tabular format based on parameters. 2. Yes, I understand the structures are different and again I would say that same thing that the data should come in tables based on structure. 3. I want to cover all data. For better understanding, please visit `https://json-csv.com/` and paste the json output there. You will then gen an output. I want a similar output in google sheets without going to the `https://json-csv.com/` website.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about your goal, yet. But when I found the vision of goal, I would like to think of your solution. I apologize that I cannot post the answer soon.

Comment: My issue is resolved. I used the code from here and it worked `https://github.com/bradjasper/ImportJSON/blob/master/ImportJSON.gs`

Comment: Thank you for providing the information. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error is not related to the app script.
This is your google sheet issue, you need to freeze the header of the sheet.
Steps:
1) Select the header row
2) Go to sheet menu View > Freeze > 1 row
check the screenshot

For more details see following screenshot:

[image]